# Algebra in Python (something better than a switch?)

Tags: python, algebra

I've built a socket server that listens for commands from another client machine (the code to which I don't have access to). The client sends a number which relates to key strokes and sends a modifier code which relates to the modifier key presses. So for example

```
shift=1
control=2
alt=4
win=8
```

The modifier code sent is always one number. e.g. modifier=1. But if more than 1 key is being sent it could be say modifier=3 (i.e. shift+control). The question is how I work out what the keys are from the number.

So to make this simple lets use a,b,c,d- Rules are only one of each in a combination.

So if:

```
a=1
b=2
c=4
d=8
```

Then these are the total number of combinations:

```
a+b=> 3
a+c=> 5
a+d=> 9
b+d=> 10
c+b=> 6
c+d=> 12

a+b+c=> 7
a+b+d=> 11

a+b+c+d=> 15
```

So what is the best way of calcuating n in Python? A switch?

```
switch(n):
    case 3:
        print 'its a+b'
     case 5:
         print 'its a+c'
```

...etc..

there must be a better way right?

Comment: "Bit field" would be an interesting search.

Comment: (I know you probably meant "switch" only by analogy, but for the record Python doesn't have a switch statement like C's.)

Comment: What was wrong with `a+c+d` and `b+c+d`?

Comment: nothing @jonrsharpe ! just missed those two :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the power of [bitwise arithmetic](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

```
def switches(n, num=4):
    return [n & (2**i) > 0 for i in range(num)]
```

This will return a list where each item is a boolean indicating whether that switch is pressed:

```
>>> switches(10)
[False, True, False, True]
#  a      b     c      d
```

---

This is why the components are all powers of 2 - it makes it trivial to access the value of each switch, when you consider the total as a binary number (note reversed order):

```
>>> format(10, 'b') # show 10 as a binary number
'1010'
#8421
#dcba
```

To show all of the options:

```
>>> for i in range(2**4):
    print(i, '\t', format(i, '04b'))


0    0000 # no switches
1    0001 # a only
2    0010
3    0011
4    0100
5    0101
6    0110
7    0111 # a, b and c
8    1000
9    1001
10   1010 # b and d
11   1011
12   1100
13   1101
14   1110
15   1111 # all switches
```

Comment: also, at least use `<<` instead of `**` if you handle bit fields

Comment: many thanks. Having never studied comp sci at uni and worked through the php ranks into python I do feel totally at sea when it comes to "bits" and anything involving maths... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use [bitwise operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) to check for the different keys. The constants are chosen, so that each modifier is represented by a different bit.

```
MOD_SHIFT       = 0b00000001  # ==  1
MOD_CONTROL     = 0b00000010  # ==  2
MOD_ALT         = 0b00000100  # ==  4
MOD_WIN         = 0b00001000  # ==  8
```

This means, you can represent more than one modifier key being pressed by `or`ing the individual values together.

```
MOD_ALT|MOD_WIN = 0b00001100  # == 12
```

On the other side, if you want to know whether a specific key is pressed, use `and`ing.

```
if keys_pressed & MOD_SHIFT:
    print "Shift key is pressed."
```

It's hard to say how to handle this in your specific case. I guess you really don't want to just print out the pressed keys. Give us more information and we might be able to help better.

Comment: Yes, but `0x00001000` is not 8.

Comment: @thg435: brain fart. but you could have edited my answer instead of cracking wise, you know?

Comment: sorry if my comment offended you, and thanks for fixing.

Comment: @thg435: no offense taken! i was serious: feel free to fix such glaring errors yourself