# How to access list elements with a binary-patern (bitwise) counting in python

Tags: python, list, binary

I am having a difficulty in finding a way to access some list elements that are represented on a binary access pattern. What I mean is:

Suppose that we have a binary number `Bin` of 4 digits: `Bin = 0b0000`
We also have a list (or set or tuple, does not matter) of same length as Bin, lets say: `list = [A, B, C, D]`

Now, I want to combinatory access the elements that are represented by `1` in `Bin` meaning that as the counter increments +1 on each loop if we are at `Bin = 0b0101` (which means Bin = 10)  then I want to access the corresponding indices, hence `B` and `D` elements in the list.

Same goes until the loop ends when `Bin = 0b1111` or `Bin = 15` where I finally access all elements of list `A, B, C, D`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean a powerset?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes since binary is 2^n where n is the length but how am I supposed to check the `1` in the number? Use an operator maybe?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24098573/3001761).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Great link. Its very compact this solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a powerset generator used on the M.I.T 6.00x course.

```
def powerSet(items):
    n = len(items)
    for i in xrange(2**n):
        combo = []
        for j in xrange(n):  
            #print i,j,(i >> j) % 2 == 1 # uncomment to see the values through the loop
            # test bit jth of integer i
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(items[j])
        yield combo
print list(powerSet([1,2,3,4]))
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

`if (i >> j) % 2 == 1` can also be written as `if (i >> j) & 1`

It uses  the `>>` [Bitwise Operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

*x >> y
Returns x with the bits shifted to the right by y places. This is the same as //'ing x by 2**y.*

Comment: There's a much neater implementation in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it helped me learn about powersets and the how the `>>` operator worked, I know there are better implementations but this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the full power-set:

```
def bin_access(iterable, index):
    return [b for a,b in zip(reversed(bin(index)[2:]), iterable) if a=='1']
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation or comments? Thanks